# How to pass models to Ember.js view / application template?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to build my app's navigation dynamically based on model data.

In my `application` template, I'm including a view for the navigation:

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>My App</h1>
  {{view App.NavView}}
</div>
```

Here's `App.NavView`:

```
App.NavView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'nav'
});
```

And the `nav` template:

```
<ul class="nav">
  {{#each contentTypes}}
    <li><a href="#">{{name}}</a></li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

As you can see, I want to loop over `contentTypes` and display the `name` of each. Getting these Ember Data models is simple:

```
App.ContentType.find()
```

But where do I put this call so that my `NavView`/`nav` template has access to the array of models? Should `NavView` make the call? Or do I make them available to the application template? How?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the `{{render}}` [helper](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/rendering-with-helpers/). You can either use defaults that the corresponding controller would provide or pass in a model along with the context.

`{{render}}` is similar to `{{outlet}}` but you provide the context.

The markup changes to,

```
<div class="container">
<h1>My App</h1>
{{render 'contentTypes'}}
</div>
```

And I added a corresponding contentTypes template

```
<script type='text/x-handlebars' data-template-name='contentTypes'>
<ul class="nav">
  {{#each contentTypes}}
    <li><a href="#">{{name}}</a></li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
</script>
```

Here's a [Jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/exetot/2) with the contentTypes hardcoded on a `ContentTypesController`. Your implementation would have contentTypes coming via the model.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the context to the rendered view into a target outlet with the [`{{#link-to}}`](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/links/#toc_the-code-link-to-code-helper) helper in your [`{{#each}}`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_each) block, like so:

```
<script type='text/x-handlebars' data-template-name='contentTypes'>
<ul class="nav">
  {{#each contentTypes}}
    <li>{{#link-to "routeName" this}}{{name}}{{/link-to}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
</script>
```